# Java program to call REST service that needs authentication

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, post

```
public class RestClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("fromSku","NONE" );
        jsonObject.put("toSku","ASA5500-ENCR-K8" );
        jsonObject.put("modelNo", "ASAV10");
        jsonObject.put("serialNo", "ASATSTSN");
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

         URL url = new URL("http://licruleswb-               dev.cloudapps.cisco.com/LicenseRules/rest/invokeASARule");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        String encodedCredentials = new String(
                    org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
                    (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("username:password"))
                    );

            System.out.println(encodedCredentials);
            connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", encodedCredentials);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonObject.toString());
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println(in.toString());
            while (in.readLine() != null) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            }
            System.out.println("\nREST Service Invoked Successfully..");
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nError while calling REST Service");
            System.out.println(e);
        }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Output:

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://wwwin-sso-nprd.cisco.com/obrareq.cgi?wh%3Dlicruleswbintrtpdev-licensingrules.cloudapps.cisco.com%20wu%3D%2FLicenseRules%2Frest%2FinvokeASARule%20wo%3D2%20rh%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flicruleswb-dev.cloudapps.cisco.com%20ru%3D%252FLicenseRules%252Frest%252FinvokeASARule">here</a>.</p>
null

REST Service Invoked Successfully..
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue. This link is working perfectly fine if used in REST Client ad on But with this java program it's throwing a 302 error.

Comment: The server responds with a Redirect. If you want to implement it yourself with `url.openConnection()`, you'll have to write code to deal with it - or use something like apache httpclient, which makes it much easier: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ BTW: 302 is not an error!

Comment: Ok.. I tried using HttpClient also but there also authentication is not happening and throwing me 401 Authentication Failure as a response. Can you help me out to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your thread when trying something similar. For me the problem was solved by concatenating "Basic " with `encodedCredentials` variable, making it "Basic EncodedValue".